# dynamically generate columns per date in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have table where number of errors made by an employee is stored.

```
i_empid error_category  error_count    date    
    13           1              1      1-feb-2017                                             
    13           2              1      1-feb-2017
    13           2              2      3-feb-2017
    341          1              1      3-feb-2017
```

I want result set to group by error category for particular date

```
  error_category  error_count    1-feb-2017     2-feb-2017     3-feb-2017
        1              2            1              0              1         
        2              0            1              0              2
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? It often does make a difference whether you're using MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle, SQL Server or IBM DB2 - or something else even. Please add a relevant tag to your question!

Comment: Its for Sql server

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza right, that's the job for pivot

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what database you use, is it MySQL?

I think youre trying to do something like this:

```
select t.error_category, t.error_count, sum(IF(t.date='1-feb-2017',1,0)) as `1-feb-2017`,
sum(IF(t.date='3-feb-2017',1,0)) as `3-feb-2017`
from <yourTable> t
group by t.error_category
```

There are different ways to archieve this actually